# Button OnClick action initiated after 6 seconds in android

Tags: android, android-button

I have 5 buttons in my activity inside a linear layout.
I have written a code to display a toast message when I click one of those buttons.
It is displaying the toast message after 6 seconds of Click action.
I couldn't think what the problem could be..
Here is the code I have written in android studio

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

     private Button loginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        makeNotificationBarTransparent();

        loginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_btn);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);





        Intent i = getIntent();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),i.getStringExtra("UserName"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void makeNotificationBarTransparent() {
        //Making notification bar transparent
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.login_btn:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"CLicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me What could be the problem?

Comment: On what are you testing this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Try adding using logcat to check when the click is handled: `Log.d("FOO", "view_id=" + v.getID()` before your `switch` statement. Follow via "adb logcat | grep FOO" and see when you see the messages

Comment: I am testing this on my own android phone (API 23) through adb using USB

Comment: It is detecting the click.Its returning this. '07-18 02:39:33.567 25590-25590/ssapps.com.smilesalon_0 D/FOO: view_id=2131558485'. But the click is detected only after a few seconds

Comment: Try moving your makeNotificationBarTransparent() to after your button's onClickListener. I could see the first method slowing some things down.

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion. The problem is with my backgroud image resolution. Its slowing my app down.

Answer (score 2):

It might be the fact that you show another toast message that you set to show up, as two toast messages cannot display at once.

I am referring to this toast message:

```
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),i.getStringExtra("UserName"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I have removed the other Toast message and the problem still exists

Comment: @VidyaSagar do you have anything running that might be occupying a lot of memory? It could just be that something is slowing your app down.

Comment: Ya. You may be right. I have a 2,45MB .png file serving as a background image in my layout. Although I have to ask, does the size of the image can slow down my app or is it resolution?

Answer (score 0):

You mean the Toast message will be show after clicking the button for 6 seconds?
Try to use this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               // show toast here...
           }
    }, 6000); // 6 seconds
```

Or you can use CountDownTimer:

```
new CountDownTimer(6000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
       // do every 1 second
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        // show your toast after 6 seconds.
    }

}.start();
```

Is this what you need? If not, tell me more about your problems :)

Comment: Without using anything, my Toast message is showing after few seconds of click action. I want it to be shown instantly as I click.

Comment: In your code above, where you use putExtra()? (I mean you getStringExtra from where?)

Comment: I get the String from my previous activity through  intent. I have waited till that toast disappeared and then clicked on button. still It shows its toast after few seconds only. I have logged the view using Log.d("Id",v.getId()). I could conclude that app is listening to the click only after a few seconds after its actually clicked, instead of recognizing the click immediately. Any idea why that could happen?

Comment: Exactly...I couldnt figure out why this is happening